# Select columns from a view and tables together and multiply columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have two tables and one view. The one table is `products` and the other is `suppliers` and the view is `v_orders_customers`.

The table `products` has  the following columns:

- product_id(primary key)
- product_price
- product_name

The `customers` table has the following columns:

- customer_id
- first_name

The view `v_orders_customers` has the following columns:

- order_id
- customer_id
- order_date
- order_quantity
- product_id

The query that I want to make is:

"Select the following information (customer name, order number, order date, order value) for those orders whose value is greater than $ 8,000.

Tip: The value of an order is the product of the value of the product unit on the order quantity. Use the v_orders_customers".

My problem is how can I take columns from the tables and the view and multiply also to make that query.

EDIT:Here is my attempt butit is not finished because I don't know how to continue..

`SELECT customers.first_name,v_orders_customers.order_id,v_orders_customers.order_date,(v_orders_customers.order_quantity * product_price) 
FROM VIEW v_orders_customers,TABLE customers,TABLE products
WHERE (...);`

Comment: you know something about formatting? it's unreadable

Comment: please show the structure of your tables (dummy create(s) and sample data would help). and also showing your attempts

Comment: "Tip: The value of an order is the product..." is this an exam question?

Comment: @PaulBambury no it's a tip that i created to make people here understand what I mean by saying order value..

Comment: LOL. Ok. I see you've added your code. Looks like you're half way there. The problem with your query as it stands is that you while you can test the for rows where (v_orders_customers.order_quantity * product_price) > 8000, that's only going to work for each order line, whereas you want (I assume) the whole order value. So you need to introduce an aggregate function to sum up the value of the order. Have a read through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx and see how you get on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't use implicit joins (having multiple tables in the `from` clause) - they have been deprecated for quite a few years now, and are considered a bad practice. Instead, you should explicit joins. As for the `where` clause - you can use expression in it, just like in the `select` list:

```
SELECT c.first_name,
       v.order_id,
       v.order_date,
       (v.order_quantity * p.product_price) AS total_price
FROM   customers c
JOIN   v_orders_customers v ON v.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN   products p ON p.product_id = v.product_id
WHERE  v.order_quantity * p.product_price > 8000
```